# Problems with middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware

Laravel is ignoring my middleware. I have a middleware that checks that you have billing information on our website. If you have them but they are not validated by the administrator, the middleware must continue blocking. Or, if they are rejected.

```
class HasBilling {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

       $user_profile = UsersProfile::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
        if (!is_object($user_profile) && !\Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('soy-agente') && !\Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('soy-agente_inversor')) {
            return redirect()->route('myaccount.facturacion.ver')->with('error', 'No posees datos de facturación. Antes de usar algunas funciones como facturación, publicidad, merkado, tarifas... debes rellenar los datos.');
        }

        if(is_object($user_profile) && is_null($user_profile->validate)){
            return redirect()->route('myaccount.facturacion.ver')->with('error', 'Tus datos de facturación están pendiente de validar');
       
        }

        if(is_object($user_profile) && $user_profile->validate == 2)){
            return redirect()->route('myaccount.facturacion.ver')->with('error', 'Tus datos de facturación han sido rechazados.');
       
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

The part where "user_profile" is not an object works. But the other two ifs are completely ignored. Since objects with "validate" null or whose value is "2" do not work.

My middleware registered on Kernel:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'hasbilling' => \App\Http\Middleware\HasBilling::class,
];
```

My middleware applied:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);

    $this->middleware('hasbilling');
}
```

Somebody can help me? I don't know where it could be failing.

Answer (score 0):

So this looks like a logic error. If the first block is being executed then the middleware is being used, unless another middleware does the same thing.

You can always dump the $user_profile in the middleware and see what data is actually being checked against. `dd($user_profile);`

Answer (score 0):

You have not inherited `Middleware` class.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
    
class HasBilling extends Middleware
{
...
```

Comment: Hi, i tried to extens Middleware, but i got this error `Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Middleware' not found `

Comment: @XQUJAGGER Include namespaces on top of the file.

Comment: i got this namespace and includes: `namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\UsersProfile;
use App\UsersProfileAutorizado;
` and doesnt work

Comment: @XQUJAGGER Still throwing  `Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Middleware' not found` error?

Comment: Yes bro, i dont know

Comment: @XQUJAGGER Trying apply middleware in route.